# Windows management instrumentation for dummies?

Tags: windows, wmi

Please can someone explain Windows Management Instrumentation in simple terms?

Why it is important?

What you can do with it?

I've read the wikipedia page and am none the wiser :)

Answer (score 2):

Windows Management Instrumentation is a core Windows management technology; you can use WMI to manage both local and remote computers. WMI provides a consistent approach to carrying out day-to-day management tasks with programming or scripting languages. For example, you can:

1. Start a process on a remote computer.
2. Schedule a process to run at specific times on specific days.
3. Reboot a computer remotely.
4. Get a list of applications installed on a local or remote computer

For example, run following command in a admin CMD, it will return details about your computer.

wmic path win32_operatingsystem get /value

Comment: Could you possibly include a source for your information? You should also note that due to the age of this question it is unlikely that you receive any positive replies from the OP.

Comment: i am new guy for this forum, i didn't notice this is a aged thread. I have lots of material about WMI, and i have few years' of WMI supporting experience, so i just want to share something with the OP. So i need to delete my answer?

Comment: Not at all! It is a good answer, what would make it a *great* answer is a link to a source so if the OP is still around they can do some additional reading around the subject. Take a look at [answer] for tips. All first posts get reviewed as a matter of course which is how yours came up.